# Adobe photoshop - update shape color

Tags: adobe-photoshop

It's possible to auto update the fill color of a shape ( rectangle ) when the selected color (foreground/background) changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so, since the Rectangle Tool (and the other shape tools) uses their own Fill color (found top left of the screen) and not the general, one beneath the tools panel.